# Need to change properties in JPA entity associated with populated database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, h2

I have a Spring MVC/Hibernate app with currently one populated H2 database table based on this entity:

```
//annotations...
public class AnEntity implements Serializable {

    //ID...

    private String date_1;

    private String date_2;

    // Other properties

    // getters, setters, etc...
```

I need to have the entity string objects be LocalDate objects & the comparable db char columns be of type date.

I looked but cannot find information on how to best do this. Can anyone tell me what my options are?

Do I need to create another entity with the property types I need, let the app create the new table, then copy my existing table to the new one (via the h2-console and convert char to date? Or write app code to convert type then insert in new table?)

I am afraid that if I just change the property types in my existing entity, I will lose my data.

My hibernate hbm2ddl.auto property is currently set at "update".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use an H2 Database if you are afraid to lose you data. H2 is primarily used as an in-memory database which means it stores the data in memory and will not persist data on disk.

Since Java 8, the new Java Date and Time API is available for dealing with temporal values in entities. The types from the java.time package are directly mapped to corresponding SQL types. So there's no need to explicitly specify @Temporal annotation:

LocalDate is mapped to DATE. LocalTime and OffsetTime are mapped to TIME
Instant. LocalDateTime, OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime are mapped to TIMESTAMP

This means that we can mark these fields only with @Basic (or @Column) annotation, like this:

```
@Basic
private java.time.LocalDate date_1;
```

If your hibernate hbm2ddl.auto property is set at "update", database schema will be updated by comparing the existing database schema with the entity mappings.

But if you want persistent data, my advice would be to maintain an SQL Schema file  of your database, create SQL patches and don't let hibernate manage your database schema (creation / changes).

Comment: @antione.lange: That's amazing it allows you to just change property type. Thanks also for the other tips!